# Rtsp for android studio

Tags: android-studio, rtsp

I'm currently making a project on android studio and I need to take the rtsp of an action camera and and then display the live feed on the app I'm working with. Problem is, I can't find any tutorials that might help me with my problem. I'm pretty new with Android Studio and I kind of need tutorials to make sure I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Playing RTSP streams on Android, or on any device, can be tricky as the RTSP and RTP specifications support many features and options.

For experience on Android VLC is probably the most reliable playback but ExoPlayer can work also.

You can use VLC directly in your Android app - see samples here:

- https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples

Or you can use ExoPlayer - see how to add your test URL simply to the ExoPlayer test app here:

- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/pull/3854#issuecomment-841167938

From my experience, given how RTSP support can be tricky, I usually test the URL on the standalone Android VLC player first to make sure the link works.