# RTSP player on Android devices

Tags: android, rtsp, exoplayer

I am new in the world of programming android app. I am trying to make an android app that let me view an RTSP video stream of my Reolink E1 Pro camera. Then I will add more features that are not related to RTSP video so they are not important. I have tried both VLClib and Exoplayer. At the moment I am using Exoplayer as RTSP player and when I test the app with the Android Studio emulator, all the devices that I test, run the app with no problem. When I connect my real smartphone to the PC and try to run the application, everything is fine except for the fact that the stream doesn't start and therefore the result is the black screen in the Exoplayer player. In reality the screen does not remain black but presents a gif which is loaded as long as the video buffers but it will never end to buffer. The gif is only an ImageView placed on the Exoplayer player that is visible only during buffering time. The RTSP stream is a black screen during this period. Very very rarely, after infinite attempts with the same code, the stream starts but it is a set of distorted pixels that cannot even compose a correct frame. it's not a problem related to the RTSP stream because if I use the VLC app on my smartphone, I can see the stream perfectly without any problems always at the first try. Also using the Reolink app I can see perfectly the stream. When I try to use my app with my smartphone, in the Logcat of Android Studio, I can see an infinite succession of lines that say from RtpH264Reader: `Received RTP packet with unexpected sequence number. Expected: 61465; received: 61531. Dropping packet.`. The number change in all the lines. It's not the same number repeated.

This is the java code I am using:

**Home.java**

```
package fexaquarium.sytes.net;

import static android.view.View.GONE;
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ExoPlayer player;
    private StyledPlayerView styledPlayerView;
    private MediaSource source;
    private ImageView fullscreenButton;
    private ImageView playButton;
    private ImageView bufferingGif;
    private boolean fullscreen = false;
    private boolean playing = false;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private boolean isLoggedIn;
    @SuppressLint("AuthLeak") private final String url = "rtsp://user:password@myRTSPlink:port";

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (RememberUser.getUserName(Home.this).length() == 0) {
            Intent login = new Intent(Home.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(login);
        } else {
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        //Binding elements
        styledPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.styledVideoView);
        fullscreenButton = styledPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);
        playButton = styledPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        bufferingGif = findViewById(R.id.bufferingGif);
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        //Setting RTSP video height
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int videoWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int videoHeight = (int)((float) videoWidth * 1440 / 2560);
        styledPlayerView.getLayoutParams().width = videoWidth;
        styledPlayerView.getLayoutParams().height = videoHeight;
        styledPlayerView.requestLayout();


        player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

        //Toggle fullscreen
        fullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if(fullscreen) {
                fullscreenButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Home.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen));
                styledPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
                styledPlayerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
                    getSupportActionBar().show();
                }
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) styledPlayerView.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                params.height = videoHeight;
                styledPlayerView.setLayoutParams(params);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

                fullscreen = false;
            } else {
                fullscreenButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Home.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit));
                styledPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH);
                styledPlayerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) styledPlayerView.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                styledPlayerView.setLayoutParams(params);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(GONE);

                fullscreen = true;
            }
        });

        //Toggle play/pause
        playButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if(playing) {
                playButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Home.this, R.drawable.ic_play));
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                playing = false;
            } else {
                playButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Home.this, R.drawable.ic_pause));
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                playing = true;
            }
        });

        //Buffering
        player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef")
            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int playbackState) {
                Player.Listener.super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState);
                switch (playbackState) {
                    case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                        bufferingGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asGif().load(R.drawable.buffering).into(bufferingGif);
                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_READY:
                        bufferingGif.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).clear(bufferingGif);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        source = new RtspMediaSource.Factory().createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri));
        player.setMediaSource(source);
        player.setVolume(0);
        styledPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.prepare();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            finishAffinity();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my layout:

**home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.078">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/styledVideoView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_controls"
            app:resize_mode="fill">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bufferingGif"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/buffering"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.994" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_pressed"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnMeasure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_measurements"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_pressed"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_pressed"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml I set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

In the **exo_controls.xml** file, I have a simple RelativeLayout with the play/pause button and the fullscreen button.

There are definitely errors in my code since I don't know well neither android nor java. In any case, on the Android studio emulator I can get the app to work without problems but on my mobile I just can't. I discovered that it happens only when I use a remote connection. I wish I could see my RTSP streaming as smoothly as if I was using VLC or the Reolink app from a remote internet connection like my mobile phone connection. In my modem I opened the right port of the camera and I am using a free DDNS (No-Ip). I hope someone can help me because I searched on the internet but I can't find solutions to my problem and I would love to complete this little project.

Comment: RTSP on Android can be hard to get working smoothly - see the link at the answer here for a way to test an RTSP stream against the ExoPlayer test app which may be your best starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68649911/334402

Comment: @Mick thanks for the answer. I tried to test my stream with the Exoplayer test app and I got the same result. On the emulator all is working fine and on my phone I can't see anything. Anyway I discovered that on my phone I can't see anything only if I am using the mobile connection. If I use my home WiFi, all is working good. The final result should be something that can be viewed from a remote connection so the problem still persist in my case.

Comment: There may be an issue with the RTSP stream being properly delivered over your mobile network. You could try logging the received packets and compare how they look over wifi and your mobile network.